# System.Net.WebClient Class in .Net CompactFramework 3.5?

Tags: compact-framework, webclient, system.net

I need to comunicate with a Server that give me async answers (streamer connection).

I find this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms144211%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

that generate this event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.net.webclient.openreadcompleted%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

I think this is what i need, but i don't have the WebClient class in my System.Net of CompactFramework 3.5.

How can i do?

Thanks.

EDIT: I've done a more clear question:
[httpRequest, httpResponse, send GET through Stream and Receive the Result in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633132/httprequest-httpresponse-send-get-through-stream-and-receive-the-result-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is .NET desktop framework, and you need .NET CF. It's not clear (for me) what kind of streaming you need. Is it regular HTTP / HTTPS protocol or something more custom? If it's HTTP, you can use [HTTP client component](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-https.php) of our SecureBlackbox for your needs.

Comment: i need to send a message, and wait for a return message. This message can arrive a lot of time after my send, so i need the OpenReadASync function, for have an event when i have an answer, and don't must create a thread with a while for check an answer.

Comment: @Leen15 async. method will create a secondary thread for you anyway

Comment: can you tell me how can i do for replicate the OpenReadASync function?

Comment: @Leen15 - with built-in classes - no idea. With our HTTP client component - you are welcome to use our support channels ( http://www.eldos.com/sbb/support-tech.php ) where our developers will be happy to assist you.