# httpRequest, httpResponse, send GET through Stream and Receive the Result in C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, stream, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

This is what i'm trying to do:

- Connect to a http service
- From here, i need to get a STREAM for comunicate with that.
- Now, i send GET request, and the service answer me.
- Then, after the first GET request and the answer, i need to intercept everytime the service send me something.

How can i do?

I'm trying from yesterday with httRequest, httResponse, GetResponseStream and so on, but not working :(

How can i have the stream to "talk" with the service sending the GET request?

all this for NETCF 3.5.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of how to do it synchronously

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "text/html";

Stream reader = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
```

and here an asynchronous sample

```
///........
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "text/html";

IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(RequestCallback, request);
///........

private void RequestCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
     var request = ar.AsyncState as WebRequest;
     Stream reader = request.EndGetResponse(ar).GetResponseStream();
     //use this reader to read the content
}
```

Comment: Sorry, where i write the GET request?

Comment: i don't understand.. I need to send a GET request, the server answer me, and i need to confirm to receive the answer with another GET. I think for this i need to have a stream to write the request and wait for the answer. no? In your example i send a single GET request and the server answer. but the operation finally there, i need to have a constant comunication with the server. is not possible? Thanks

Comment: If i understand correctly this is not possible (as far as i know) you send a request and then get a response and if you need more communication you send another request, I don't think you can have an open duplex channel (maybe I am wrong)

Comment: this should work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.80).aspx but the result have a lot of data that is not important..:(